# Erro converter data e hora Query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Galera, estou tentando executar a consulta abaixo, porém, está ocorrendo o seguinte erro. "Falha ao converter data e/ou hora da cadeia de caracteres.".
Já realizei algumas outras conversões, mas sem sucesso.

```
select
    MesID,Mes,Ano,
cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), horas_uteis))/60 as nvarchar(3)) + ':' + cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), horas_uteis))%60 as nvarchar(2))
 as horas
from (
    select
        dbo.FN_CALC_HORAS_UTEIS(s.SolDataFechamento,min(l.LogData)) as horas_uteis,
        datepart(month,s.SolDataFechamento) MesID,
        datename(month,s.SolDataFechamento) Mes,
        datepart(year,s.SolDataFechamento) Ano
    from Solicitacao S
        left join usuario U on (U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel) 
        left join Status ST on S.SolStatus = ST.CodStatus
        left join Log L on L.LogSolID = s.SolID and (l.LOGDESCRICAO like '%1057%' or l.LOGDESCRICAO like '%3343%')
    where
        S.proid in (2)
        and S.UsuIDResponsavel in (1776)
        and s.SolStatus = 9
        and convert(date,s.SolDataFechamento) between '01-01-2018' and getdate()--and s.SolID = 65513
        group by s.SolDataFechamento
) as X
group by MesID, Mes, Ano
```

Comment: O formato padrão do sql para datas é 'yyyy-mm-dd', você deve estar recebendo o erro por conta disso, visto que no seu where é apresentado um `'01-01-2018'`

Comment: Ou qualquer coisa tenta um convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o CONVERT(DATE, *nomeDoCampo*, 105) já que utiliza a data no formato italiano dd-mm-yyyy https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

```
select
    MesID,Mes,Ano,
    cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), horas_uteis))/60 as
    nvarchar(3)) + ':' + cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time),horas_uteis))%60 as nvarchar(2))
as horas
from (
select
    dbo.FN_CALC_HORAS_UTEIS(s.SolDataFechamento,min(l.LogData)) as horas_uteis,
    datepart(month,s.SolDataFechamento) MesID,
    datename(month,s.SolDataFechamento) Mes,
    datepart(year,s.SolDataFechamento) Ano
from Solicitacao S
    left join usuario U on (U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel) 
    left join Status ST on S.SolStatus = ST.CodStatus
    left join Log L on L.LogSolID = s.SolID and (l.LOGDESCRICAO like '%1057%' or l.LOGDESCRICAO like '%3343%')
where
    S.proid in (2)
    and S.UsuIDResponsavel in (1776)
    and s.SolStatus = 9
    and convert(date,s.SolDataFechamento,105) between '01-01-2018' and convert(date,getdate(),105) --and s.SolID = 65513
    group by s.SolDataFechamento
) as X
group by MesID, Mes, Ano
```

Comment: show de bola @Carlos T.Gomes.